# Spinner not working properly in Listview

Tags: android

I am using spinner in a listview but it is not working properly in the listview. I am able to display required values in the spinner but cannot get the item selected value from the spinner.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        holder.spinner.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                String selected = holder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                System.out.println("selected = " + selected);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            }
        });
```

It is not printing anything.
Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView      
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/unisex" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/location" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/location" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/person" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner5"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView20"
        android:background="@drawable/primary_square_edittext" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_btn_gradient"
        android:text="@string/add_cart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button13"
        android:background="@drawable/login_btn_gradient"
        android:text="@string/view_detail"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout screen also

Comment: Post your `adapter` you set to spinner.

Comment: This could be a help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809526/listview-with-spinner-inside-1st-item-of-the-listview-affects-its-last-item

Comment: Maybe your `arrayList` is an empty list. You need to check your `arrayList`

Answer (score 0):

ok  this my code for spinner look at it

```
final List<governatemodel> Go_data =  governat_data[0].getAllGovernante();
        final String[] governate_final_data = new String[Go_data.size()];
        for (int i = 0 ; i<Go_data.size() ; i++)
        {
            governate_final_data[i] = Go_data.get(i).getName();
        }
          final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> langAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(IntoductionActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_text, governate_final_data );
        langAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown);
        governate_Spinner.setAdapter(langAdapter2);
        governate_Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (position != 0)
                {
                    governate_id_value = Go_data.get(position).getId();
                    String xx = Go_data.get(position).getName()+" ID is " + Go_data.get(position).getId();
                    Toast.makeText(IntoductionActivity.this, xx, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    governate_id_value = 0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: ok  do you put all data of spinner adapter in List<String> strings

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            String selected = holder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Log.i("selected = " , "" + selected);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        }
    });
```

Use getSelecteditem() method to get selected item

Comment: try the given answer, it would return you a value that is selected

Comment: If it is so, then just put the break points and test what it is returning, because we are not sure how you are setting values in your adapter

Comment: setOnItemSelectedListener is not being called.